# Rewrite rule index.php?/controller/method/param to /controller/method/param

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule for this url

```
http://localhost/~user/frame/lib/index.php?/controller/method/12/22/
```

How can i rewrite it that i can call it like this

```
http://localhost/~user/frame/lib/controller/method/12/22/
```

What is the rewrite rule for the above problem? 
I hope i could explain my question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule $2 !^index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(/~[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)(/.*)? $1/index.php?$2
```

Depending on where you want to use this rule (my suggestion is meant for the server/virtual host configuration), you may need to remove the contextual path prefix from the pattern. So if you want to use the rule in the .htaccess file in */~user/*:

```
RewriteRule $2 !^index\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)(/.*)? $1/index.php?$2
```

Or if in */~user/frame/lib/*:

```
RewriteRule $0 !^index\.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)lib/(.*)$ / $1lib/index.php?/$2
```

That's the simplest way, but not the most robust as it might screw with other URLs.  So it's worth checking thoroughly, or posting your entire .htaccess file.