# User View Profile

Tags: php, url, mapping

I am building an application for my client and I am not using any frameworks . Question came up when building viewing user profile

My client wants to see the user profile URL like

mywebsite.com/Johnd   - should give Johnd profile
mywebsite.com/KJohns   - should give KJohns   profile

I have implemented URL mapping like http://mywebsite.com/viewprofile.php?id=Johnd . But I am not sure how to map viewprofile.php?id=Johnd to just 'Johnd' .

Could some body please advise ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [easiest way to make pretty urls e.g mysite/page1 rather than mysite?page=page1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167741/easiest-way-to-make-pretty-urls-e-g-mysite-page1-rather-than-mysitepagepage1)

Comment: Thanks Gordon , Searched it , but could not get the correct phrase to search it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite might be what you're looking for (if you're running apache at least).
Have a look at http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite for a brief intro/tutorial to see if that's the type of thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache, adding a rule to your `.htaccess` file that says:

```
RewriteRule .*/profiles/(.*) viewprofile.php?id=$1 [NC, L]
```

Will let people access `http://mywebsite.com/viewprofile.php?id=Johnd` through `http://mywebsite.com/profiles/Johnd`

Alternately, if you wanted to use PHP to do this, you could map all your requests to a single file and if the request is not your list of urls, assume it's a user and route it there.  (Take a look at the code for [Tweetable MVC](http://code.google.com/p/tweet-mvc/source/browse/#svn/trunk) for the basics.)

Answer (score 0):

use modrewrite and ataccess file

there is a lot of tutorials on the net called pretty url, check this one for ex.:

http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls