# Htaccess rule to make urls like this ?page=1 look like /page/1 in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

This is how my urls currently look:

```
http://mysite.com/?page=1
```

How can I make this work?:

```
http://mysite.com/page/1
```

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167741/easiest-way-to-make-pretty-urls-e-g-mysite-page1-rather-than-mysitepage-page1) on StackOverflow that asks the same question. But the accepted solution isn't working for me. Because I am using Codeigniter and my page results in a 404 perhaps because since the url pattern of a CI site is:

domain/controller/method

The system is assuming that I am requesting a controller called "page" and a method called "1" both of which of course doesn't exist. Or maybye it's due to a conflict with the other code in my htaccess file (which I downloaded from the CI wiki, it gets rid of index.php and does a few security things). Here is my entire htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users. Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller, 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder. This snippet prevents user access to the application folder. Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Pretty urls for pagination links
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1

</IfModule>
```

The non indented bit is the solution I got from that other SO question that isn't working for me.

Any solutions to this CI pagination issue?

---

### UPDATE

Ok, read some of the docs and now I have this working:

```
http://mysite.com/home/index/2
```

What would be the htaccess rule to turn that into?:

```
http://mysite.com/page/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make this configuration at `/application/config/routes.php` (and let the `.htaccess` just for hide the index.php as you are already doing).

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

Or better, like @zaherg remembered (ensures that only numbers could by matched):

```
$route['page/(:num)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

This way all the requests to `http://mysite.com/page/2` will be treated internally as `http://mysite.com/home/index/2` and so forth.

I suggest you take a look at [CodeIgniter User Guide - URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and [CodeIgniter User Guide - Tutorial − Introduction](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html).

Good luck.

Comment: CI doesn't do 301's if someone stumble's upon the actual file being executed right?

Comment: but it will be much better if you use `(:num)` this will match a segment containing only numbers. so your route will be `$route['page/(:num)'] = 'home/index/$1';`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

from [CodeIgniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

That will handle removing the `index.php`, but what happens after that depends how CodeIgniter's query string handling is set up: it can be configured to use a query string rather than a path.  See the link for more details.