# Clean and friendly URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite, routes

Similar question asked here: [Htaccess rule to make urls like this ?page=1 look like /page/1 in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134050/htaccess-rule-to-make-urls-like-this-page-1-look-like-page-1-in-codeigniter)

But I can't get the answer right.

My `routes.php`

```
$route[$key] = "home_controller/index";
$route['page/(:num)'] = 'home_controller/index/$1';
```

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My `config.php`

```
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

Can't understand the syntax.
Been looking all over in Codeigniter Docs such as; https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html
I just can't seem to find the solution for this.

`host/page/1`

Is working but not redirecting to the desired page in other words its not corresponding to it's page in the pagination

`host/?page=1`

Is working but I simply want to get rid of `?page=`

I also need to fix a path url for `host/category/?page=1`
to `host/category/page/1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Htaccess rule to make urls like this ?page=1 look like /page/1 in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134050/htaccess-rule-to-make-urls-like-this-page-1-look-like-page-1-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Hey Ricky thank you for your help first of all. I mention that link in my question and no its not helping my question.

Comment: have you try add route like : `$route ['category/page/(:any)'] = "category/?page=$1";`

Comment: yes not working

Answer (score 0):

I check your code,
As I notice your routing was fine. But your mistake in the config.php file.
Please, replace your code from

```
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', 
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

to

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
 $uri = 'https://';
} else {
 $uri = 'http://';
}
$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] = $uri;
$config['base_url'] .= 
preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';


$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your help effort first of all. I tried your code still not changing anything.

Comment: Oh, so sorry to hear it.

$route['home'] = "home_controller/index";
$route['page/(:num)'] = 'home_controller/index/$1';

try to use your index function like that;

public function index($num = null){

}

Comment: Its still not working when I debug the case and echo $page;                                            It returns Nill. (I replaced $num in $page) good try but it still staying on the main page when I try to request page/2                                                                        only when I send ?page=2 the pagination responses and the page changes.

Comment: Hey can you follow up on this thanks again

Comment: Hay, Use,
function index($num = null)
{ 
}

Comment: its not working I echo the page num echo everything that wasn't the issue.