# PHP friendly URL bug?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, friendly-url

I just started a course of implementing MVC pattern using PHP and I think I'm experiencing a bug regarding friendly URL engine. The site I'm creating has the follow URL syntax: http://[site]/[controller]/[method]/[parameters] .

Until now it works in a very simple way: I access a controller and is printed on screen which controller is beeing accessed (printed by a method from controller's class). The problem is that when I access the URL http://cursophp/cliente (a real controller) it works and when I try an inexistent controller WAMP shows an error screen that informs that the page couldn't be found; **but**, when I try to access http://cursophp/produto (also a real controller), an 404 error from Apache is exhibited! And I also tried with other words like: produto1, produto2, product, product1 ("prod" prefix) and the same 404 error is exhibited!

Using Composer or including directly the controller file with "require" results in the same problem.

Is it a known bug or am I making a mistake?

htacess content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Just adding more details:

**When I try "pro" as controller's name:**
[image]

**When I try "prod" (or any word with "prod" prefix):**
[image]

**When I try "aaaa" (or any word, of any length, that doesn't correspond to a controller's name):**
[image]

Comment: Can you share your rewrite rules from your Apache mod_rewrite?

Comment: How do I do that? I added htacess content on main message.

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806242/rewrite-rule-index-php-controller-method-param-to-controller-method-param/2811545#2811545) from an older StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in function that checking the route. Try to debug on which line it's starting show the error. However, it's impossible to suggest you a specific way of solving this problem without providing more details

Answer (score 0):

This PHP script is crappy, because it does not handle unknown controllers properly.

Instead it should respond with `HTTP404`, when the file to load cannot be located.

Generally speaking, you'd need to fix that in file `Core.php`.

Comment: I understand... But the problem is that if a controller has "prod" as prefix it shows 404 error, even if the controller file exists.

Comment: `.htacess` rewrites just anything to `index.php` ...so this could either be the script which handles these URL aliases, or eventually database records, which might be used for resolving the requests. Impossible to tell unless knowing how the PHP script processes the requests. Got any GitHub URL?